# Cheap Windows driver signing for 64 bit Windows 7

Tags: windows, certificate, code-signing, device-driver

I need to install the [libusb-win32](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/libusb-win32/wiki) driver on Windows 7 64 bit machines. This driver is open source so it is not digitally signed so I want to do this myself, but I wonder if this can be done WITHOUT paying lot of money. Is it possible to use a certificate which is NOT signed by [Verisign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verisign) or [GlobalSign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlobalSign)? Maybe self-signed or by using [StartSSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StartCom#StartSSL) instead?

And if yes, how do I do it? According to a [how-to](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/how-to#Noun), *[The Practical Truth About x64 Kernel Driver Signing](http://codefromthe70s.org/kernelsigning.aspx)*, I have to use a "cross-certificate" (and there are only six available on the Microsoft list and most of them are for CAs which are no longer active).

I don't care if the user is confronted with a warning message. I can even accept if the user has to install a special [CA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) certificate first. I only require that the driver runs without manually disabling the signature check on each Windows startup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the driver has to be cross signed by one of those specific certificates and thus the driver has to be signed by one of those CAs.  You can disable driver signing on the machine for testing purposes, but obviously you don't want to do this on production machines.  Sorry, that's just the way it is.

Comment: And there is no way to inject a custom CA certificate so Windows accepts drivers signed by this custom CA?

Comment: No, the driver needs to be cross-signed with one of the certificates Microsoft provides.  You can add your own CA certificate, but without a matching cross-signing certificate it's not going to help you; only Microsoft can generate the cross-signing certificates.

Comment: Microsoft's Root CA (to which you connect your certificate with a cross-certificate) is baked deep into the kernel; it's unrelated to the certificate store. While you can work around SetupAPI's driver trust ranking through installing a root certificate into the certificate store, it's irrelevant for KMCS.

Answer (score 5):

LibUSB_win32 is now already signed, according to http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/libusb-win32/wiki

It says: "Vista/7/2008/2008R2 64 bit are supported from version 1.2.0.0 since a Microsoft KMCS accepted digital signature is embedded in the kernel driver libusb0.sys."

So the only thing you have to do is update your libusb_win32 driver.

Answer (score -5):

To allow loading into kernel, you have to sign with those CA and have WHDL checked.

The only alternative would be using the [user mode driver framework](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/wdf/umdf.mspx). (but `libusb` does not support it -- it was discussed, but never implemented)

Comment: Can you explain what "WHDL checked" means?

Comment: Drivers don't need to go through WHQL to be loaded onto x64 Windows, they just need to be signed.